# LWJGL Display.create() Throws Exception

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

For a university project we need to make a game in a group of 5 people in Java. As we are writing a game in 3D first person I want to use lwjgl. I wrote up a test program on my home computer which is running Ubuntu. However I brought it to uni and tried to run it on the machines there which are Arch Linux and it threw an exception when trying to call the Display.create() method.

Here is the stack trace:

failed to create drawable
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0x7bde17a0 serial: 89 error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) request_code: 14 minor_code: 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:318)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.nMakeCurrent(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxContextImplementation.makeCurrent(LinuxContextImplementation.java:121)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.ContextGL.makeCurrent(ContextGL.java:194)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.makeCurrent(DrawableGL.java:110)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.makeCurrent(Display.java:703)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.makeCurrentAndSetSwapInterval(Display.java:1022)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:849)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:754)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:736)

I've asked around uni but no one seems to be any help as no one has used lwjgl. I can't update the graphics card drivers because it is a university machine. I also have to have it running on the uni machine as we have to present our project on it and other people in the group will be programming on them.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or is there an alternative library that can I use that uses openGL? I know there is java opengl but it doesn't seem as nice as lwjgl.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that lwjgl is trying to use `/dev/video`, if you can try running `usermod -a -G video <Your-UserName>`

[Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/36618-minecraft-crash-on-ubuntu-linux/)